# What exactly is the difference between an app specific event and a GWT event and when is one supposed to be used over the other?

Tags: java, events, gwt

While consulting the javadocs for GwtEvent class  this text snippet  got me confused:

> There is no need for an application's custom event types to extend
>   GwtEvent. Prefer Event instead.

Can someone please give a concrete situation example where Event  is preferred to the  gwtevent class?
Should ClearEvent ( defined here : http://alextretyakov.blogspot.ro/2011/11/gwt-event-bus-basics.html ) extend GwtEvent class or should it directly extend Event class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GwtEvent extends Event. It just seems that the GWT team need some functionalities for most of its events. But you probably don't need those.

In our application most events are consumed directly. So we don't need to have those isLive(), kill(), revive() methods. I guess it's the same for most people.

IMO such methods are required when a chain of listeners can catch the event and forward it to each other. You would want to mark the event as "processed" to avoid it being consumed when the processing is over.

[The code in the post you provided](http://alextretyakov.blogspot.ro/2011/11/gwt-event-bus-basics.html) is not using those methods. So the answer is: the author didn't need to extends GWTEvent. Event will work just fine.